# Formatting redox reactions with chemmacros and mhchem; arrows aren't drawn correctly

Tags: mhchem, chemistry, chemmacros

I'm using the `chemmacros` package to format redox reactions using its redox module to get the nice arrows that indicate which atoms are changing oxidation state as illustrated in the package manual.  I am trying to do something that the manual says is nonstandard and may not work, which is using the `mhchem` package to format reactions.  Nonetheless it works in one simple instance but not another and I'd appreciate any tips to get it working better.

It appears if you have `chemmacros` draw an arrow with the `\redox(a,b)` command where a and b are in the same compound, it works fine.  But if a and b are in different compounds in the reaction (two formulas separated by a + or an arrow) in the `\ce{ a + b -> c + d}` reaction, then the `chemmacros` arrow doesn't quite know where to start.

Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{redox}
\begin{document}

\ce{\OX{a,Pt}(CH2CH=CH\OX{b,C}(CH2)2) + \OX{c,Fe} + \OX{d,Zn}}\redox(a,b)[draw=red,->]{\small oxidation}
%that above command produces good output

\bigskip

\ce{\OX{a,Pt}(CH2CH=CH\OX{b,C}(CH2)2) + \OX{c,Fe} + \OX{d,Zn}}\redox(a,c)[draw=red,->]{\small oxidation}
%that above command produces bad output

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have this problem. Did you compile twice?

Comment: Bernard - yes I did.   So you can use my MWE and the second example looks good?

Comment: Quite good. I can't post the result in a comment, unfortunately. Do you have the latest version of `chemmacros` (5.5)?

Comment: Yes -- chemmacros 5.5 and mhchem 4.04.   I didn't add that figure up there, one of the editors did, so evidently they have the issue too. I'll add that I'm using TeXShop, TeXLive 2015 on a mac (Yosemite).

Comment: Try replacing `\ce` (from `mhchem`) with `\ch` (from `chemmacros`). It appears to work for me.

Comment: @Nunkulla: Strange… It didn't work for me.

Comment: @William Kennerly: Do you have version from March 8 2016?

Comment: @Bernard As well as switching `\ce` to `\ch`, it is also necessary to remove or comment out `\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}`

Comment: @Nunkulla  Thanks for that -- it does work (you have to comment out the loading of `mhchem` and then change `\ce{}` to `\ch{}`.  I'd rather use `\ce{}` so this still leaves the original question unresolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works if you place `\ce` inside `\OX` instead of the other way around:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
  formula = mhchem ,
  modules = redox
}
\begin{document}

\OX{a,\ce{Pt}}\ce{(CH2CH=CH\OX{b,C}(CH2)2) + }\OX{c,\ce{Fe}}\ce{ +}\OX{d,\ce{Zn}}
\redox(a,c)[draw=red,->]{\small oxidation}

\end{document}
```

This is one of the cases where the “natural” support package `chemformula` is easier to work with:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
  formula = chemformula ,
  modules = redox
}
\begin{document}

\ch{"\OX{a,Pt}" (CH2CH=CH\OX{b,C}(CH2)2) + "\OX{c,Fe}" + "\OX{d,Zn}"}
\redox(a,c)[draw=red,->]{\small oxidation}

\end{document}
```